# Namespace autoloading with composer and PSR-0 not working as expected

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

I have made a [test](https://github.com/rakibtg/GoWin) project to understand how composer and packagist works. The project is also on [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/rakibtg/gowin).

A simple `composer require rakibtg/gowin` will install the package from packagist.

But for some reason the namespacing is not working as expected.

Here is my directory structure and the composer file.
[image]

Here is the GoWin.php file:

```
  <?php

  namespace GoWin;

  class GoWin {
    public function serve() {
      echo 'Lets Win Everybody!';
    }
  }
```

Here is the test.php file where i am trying to use the `serve()` method from the `GoWin` class.

```
  <?php

  require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

  // use GoWin;

  ( new GoWin\GoWin() )->serve();
```

But it fails to execute the `serve` method with this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'GoWin\GoWin' not found in
>
> /Users/usr/Desktop/t estGoWin/index.php:7 Stack trace:
>
> 0 {main}   thrown in /Users/usr/Desktop/testGoWin/index.php on line 7

At this moment i cant understand what i am missing! Also should i use psr-0 or psr-4?

Comment: The autoload definition is wrong. cf. https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-0

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by switching to PSR-4, simply update the composer.json `autolaod` property as this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "GoWin\\": "src/"
    }
},
```